# How to force remove a package if dpkg removal script fails?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm trying to remove a package where I deleted the `/etc/init.d/disco-master` file (in an attempt to remove the package manually). I want to remove the `disco-master` package. How do I do this now?

This is what happens when I do `sudo apt-get remove disco-master`:

```
removing disco-master ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/disco-master not found.
dpkg: error processing disco-master (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 disco-master
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall disco-master` I get the following:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 disco-master : Depends: disco-node (= 0.4.2+nmu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I do `sudo apt-get -f install` I get this:

```
Unpacking disco-node (from .../disco-node_0.4.2+nmu1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/disco-node_0.4.2+nmu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/disco/master/ebin/disco.app', which is also in package disco-master 0.4.1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/disco-node_0.4.2+nmu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I run `sudo apt-get remove disco-node` I get the following:

```
Package disco-node is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 disco-master : Depends: disco-node (= 0.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python-disco (= 0.4.1) but 0.4.2+nmu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I did `sudo dpkg -P --force-all disco-master` I got:

```
Removing disco-master ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/disco-master not found.
dpkg: error processing disco-master (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 disco-master
```

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg -P --force-all disco-master`.

Comment: did that ... appended to question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431372/removing-broken-packages-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create a dummy initscript to fool dpkg:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/disco-master
```

Enter the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 0
```

Save the file, set execution permission (`sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/disco-master`) and try to `sudo apt-get remove disco-master` again.

Comment: I did a similar thing to the OP only with salt-master package... this answer also worked for me!

Comment: life saver Eric, u are great.

Comment: Brilliant, I had: `post-removal script returned error exit status 1`.. So, I found that script `/var/lib/dpkg/info/{package}.postrm`, went through it to verify that I had done the things in it (delete configs/files etc), then modified it to the above.. IT WORKS.. Apt works again. Amazing.  :D