# remove stuck package: subprocess installed post-installation script was killed

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, apt-cache

It failed during `dist-upgrade`. I already removed this package PPA from sources, but if I do `dist-upgrade` or `install -f`, it still tries to execute this setup script and dies:

```
Setting up yd-tools (1.8.18) ...
dpkg: error processing package yd-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was killed by signal (Terminated)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I "refuse" updating it? I mean, it is cached, but I want not to update this specific package.

```
Removing yd-tools (1.8.18) ...
dpkg: error processing package yd-tools (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script was killed by signal (Terminated)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script was killed by signal (Terminated)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 yd-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167991/how-to-force-remove-a-package-if-dpkg-removal-script-fails) also didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing `/var/lib/dpkg/info/yd-tools.postinst` with a `exit 0`
 [dummy](https://github.com/slytomcat/yandex-disk-indicator/issues/157) did the trick

Comment: What is "certain script"? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I did just remove the `prerm` script altogether.

In your case:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/yd-tools.prerm
```