# 'timeshift: Command not found' following Timeshift removal

Tags: 20.04, dpkg, error-handling, timeshift

I removed TIMESHIFT on Ubuntu and I followed the instructions in [Timeshift - GitHub's ReadMe](https://github.com/linuxmint/timeshift) but after a succesfull removal it gives me this error, how can I delete this script?

```
Rsyncing /boot/efi into the filesystem before the call to timeshift.
/usr/bin/timeshift-autosnap-apt: riga 54: timeshift: comando non trovato
Unable to run timeshift-autosnap-apt! Please close Timeshift and try again. Script will now exit...

E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Pre-Invoke '/usr/bin/timeshift-autosnap-apt'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - I went to `/usr/bin/`
> - Found `timeshift-autosnap-apt`
> - Deleted it
> - Ran the command:
>
>   ```
>   sudo nano /usr/bin/timeshift-autosnap-apt
>   ```
> - Entered the following:
>
>   ```
>   #!/bin/bash
>   exit 0
>   ```
> - Saved the file
> - Set execution permission:
>
>   ```
>   sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/timeshift-autosnap-apt
>   ```
>
> And `sudo apt upgrade` ignored the script and worked succesfully.
>
> Source that helped me to find the solution: [How to force remove a
> package if dpkg removal script fails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167991/how-to-force-remove-a-package-if-dpkg-removal-script-fails)

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1482713/2).</sup>